# How to POST a blob and JSON values using fetch

Tags: javascript

I am passing a `blob` image file to a server using the header,

`application/octet-stream`.

I need to also pass some `string` values to the server with it. If I change the header to

```
application/json
```

I can access the string, but the blob becomes undefined.

**Example**

```
  const data = {
          blob,
          firstname: 'Nichoals',
        };

fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
          .then(response => response.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            ...
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
      'image/png',
      1,
    );
```

**Things I have tried**

I have tried to pass the data using `FormData()` and was able to get the data to the server but the file was corrupt. I do think I could figure out how to get it to work this way but I would like to learn a better way to do it if possible.

**Things I do not want to do**

I do not want to convert the blob to a string because I fear that will be way to expensive.

**Question**

In what way can I `POST` an object with a `blob` and some `string` values inside of it to a server without using the way mentioned above?

*Essentially this,*

```
const data = {
      blob,
       firstname: 'Will',
 };
```

Comment: Just re-read what you've tried. `FormData` is definitely the "better" way here, and you'll need to create a [mcve] if you want help debugging the corrupt file issue you've cited as your roadblock.

Comment: No thank you, I do not need help debugging the corrupt file. I would like to figure out if there is a way to do this without using FormData(). Thank you though. If not, that is ok. I am just looking for a definite. I was surprised that this is such a hard task to accomplish and figured I would seek out a possible solution. I can't recall every having to do this before.

Comment: There is not another way to do this without either using `FormData`, stringifying the blob, or using two separate `POST`s for your blob and string values. It's really not difficult to use `FormData`, but your file corruption, based on experience is probably related to creating a UTF-8 encoded buffer rather than a binary one, which makes unicode characters with codepoints > 0x7F two bytes instead of one

Comment: I considered string but it would increase the size of the blob by 30 percent. I also considered sending another fetch in the result callback but was curious to know if there is any other solution that exists.

Comment: Would it be unreasonable to try and put the other values in their own object, convert it to a blob, then some how send the blob file and blob object to the server, then convert back from there?

Comment: I would think that is unreasonable, yes. That's already essentially what `FormData` does.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So it literally is the only real choice in this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could send the json as a header:

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Custom-Json': JSON.stringify(data)
  },
  body: blob,
}).then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    // handle response
})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```